# Romanization with Google Cloud Translation API

Tags: google-translate

Does it possible to get romanization/latinization (pronunciation using English letters) with Google Cloud Translation API?

```
   Example: 
   Рассвет -> Rassvet
   黎明 -> Límíng
```

I didn't find it in Docs, but on https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/en/%E9%BB%8E%E6%98%8E it shows.

Comment: There has been Google Transliteration API, but it's deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545769/what-to-use-instead-of-google-transliterate-api