# How to get romanization of word using google translate API (word is translated in different language but get its pronunciation form in english )

Tags: google-translate

I am trying to get translation of words using https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup API
It all works fine but I need to get the translated word in english(romanized)

For eg: If input word in english is `hello` & translated to Japanese returns `こんにちは`
But I need this translated in english `Kon'nichiwa` (like the way google translate website shows it)

[image]

Using the google translate API, it just returns the translated word in the corresponding language.
Is there anyway to achieve this ?
I am open to use any other API as well (as long as it has some free version of it)

Comment: That (Kon'nichiwa or the likes) is called "Romanization". Here is a related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750093/get-chinese-romanization-from-google-translate-api Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741036/romanization-with-google-cloud-translation-api